# HCI XmlSlurper Groovy find not found job_information records in same date

Tags: groovy, sap-cloud-platform, sap-successfactors

I need to find a record with event Hire in job_information.

```
def Message processData(Message message) {

//Get body from message 
def body = message.getBody(java.lang.String)
//Parse body
def queryCompoundEmployeeResponse = new XmlSlurper().parseText(body)

queryCompoundEmployeeResponse.CompoundEmployee.each{
  it.person.employment_information.each{
    def startDate = it.job_information.find{
      j->(j.event.text() == 'H') 
    }.start_date.text()
  }
}
```

However, for this employee, there are 2 records at the same date.
And the find function return nothing.

Anyone know how to solve this issue?

[2 records at the same date image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdGaV.png)

Comment: could you please share the data stream you are trying to search through? whats the input data? what do you want to find with your groovy script?

Comment: please provide the content of message ... whats the input to this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think less people know what you are talking about and I do not have any message from employee compound available, this is why I simulated the message of yours and try to show how to get each event type H, no matter what date it has.

This should search event H and return each person-node, no matter if date is equal to each other.

```
def stringXML = 
'<personDatabase>'+
        '  <person><firstName>John</firstName><lastName>Doe</lastName><created>2016-05-23T09:41:39.000Z</created><event>H</event></person>'+
        '  <person><firstName>Jane</firstName><lastName>Smith</lastName><created>2018-05-10T09:41:39.000Z</created><event>G</event></person>'+
        '  <person><firstName>Robert</firstName><lastName>Doe</lastName><created>2016-05-23T09:41:39.000Z</created><event>H</event></person>'+
'</personDatabase>'

def people = new XmlSlurper().parseText(stringXML)
people.person.findAll { p ->
    p.event.toString().equals('H')
}.each { p ->
    println p.created
}
```

This results in:

[image: largeResult]
    [image: shortResult]

Adapt it to your needs.

Live: https://groovy-playground.appspot.com/?_sm_au_=iVVR2FSD4MsqWj30